# ¿Cómo capturar salida de terminal con Python?

Tags: python, debian

Mi objetivo es crear un programa que tome la salida de la terminal en tiempo real y al mismo tiempo enviarla a otro programa.

Agradecería que alguien me pudiera dar las bases para hacer esta aplicación.

Comment: Hola @Tezca. ¡Bienvenido a [es.so]! ¿De qué terminal? ¿La idea es obtener el resultado de la ejecución en línea de comandos, u obtener la instancia de la salida de una terminal actual? Sería recomendable que comentes qué investigaste e intentaste, por más que no te haya funcionado. Quizás te sea útil realizar el [tour] y leer [ask].

Answer (score 2):

Depende de lo que quieras hacer, pero se usaría subprocess, aquí un enlace a [documentación en español](http://pyspanishdoc.sourceforge.net/whatsnew/node8.html) (aunque de una versión vieja).

Cito de la documentación:
"Se puede proporcionar un objeto fichero o un descriptor de fichero, o se puede usar la constante subprocess.PIPE para crear una tubería entre el subproceso y el padre."

Aquí un ejemplo básico para pasar una cadena (sacado de un hilo en [inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string)):

```
import subprocess

command = 'echo "Hola mundo"'
process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=None, shell=True)

output = process.communicate()

print(output[0])
```